# MVC The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I try to create a ticket on my create.cshtml it gives me this error. I think it's because my Category uses a dropdownlist using ViewBags while my User and Administrator dropdown list doesn't.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Ticket_dbo.Category_CategoryID". The conflict occurred in
>   database "RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext", table
>   "dbo.Category", column 'CategoryID'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

[image]

[image]

TicketController.cs

```
public class TicketController : Controller
{
    private IssueContext db = new IssueContext();

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        TicketVM model = new TicketVM();
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
        ViewBag.AllUsers = db.Users.ToList().Select(u => new SelectListItem() { Value = u.UserID.ToString(), Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", u.FirstMidName, u.LastName) });
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(TicketVM model)   
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ConfigureViewModel(model);
            return View(model);
        }
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket
        {
            Issue = model.Issue,
            IssuedTo = model.IssuedTo
        };
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
 ERROR------>   db.SaveChanges();  <------ ERROR
            return View();
        }
        ViewBag.CategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName", ticket.CategoryID);
        ViewBag.AllUsers = db.Users.ToList().Select(u => new SelectListItem() { Value = u.UserID.ToString(), Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", u.FirstMidName, u.LastName) });
        ViewBag.AllAdmins = db.Users.Where(u => u.IsAdministrator).Include(u => u.Tickets);
        return View(ticket);
    }

    private void ConfigureViewModel(TicketVM model)
    {
        IEnumerable<User> admins = db.Users.Where(u => u.IsAdministrator).OrderBy(u => u.LastName);
        model.AdministratorList = admins.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.UserID.ToString(),
            Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", a.FirstMidName, a.LastName)
        });
    }
}
```

\Views\Ticket\Create.cshtml

```
@model RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.ViewModels.TicketVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Ticket</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryID, "Category")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserID, "User")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AllUsers, "Please select")`
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserID)
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IssuedTo)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IssuedTo, Model.AdministratorList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IssuedTo)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Issue)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Issue, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Issue)
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Category.cs

```
public class Category
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

Ticket.cs

```
public enum Priority
{
    Low, Med, High
}
public class Ticket
{
    public int? TicketID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the description")]
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Administrator")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the Administrator")]
    public int IssuedTo { get; set; }
    public int Author { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Priority")]
    public Priority? Priority { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModels\TicketVM.cs

```
public class TicketVM
{
    public int? UserID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the description")]
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Administrator")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select the Administrator")]
    public int IssuedTo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AdministratorList { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
}
```

AccountController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Transactions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet;
using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Filters;
using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models;

namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/Login

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LogOff

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            WebSecurity.Logout();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Register

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Disassociate

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Disassociate(string provider, string providerUserId)
        {
            string ownerAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.GetUserName(provider, providerUserId);
            ManageMessageId? message = null;

            // Only disassociate the account if the currently logged in user is the owner
            if (ownerAccount == User.Identity.Name)
            {
                // Use a transaction to prevent the user from deleting their last login credential
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable }))
                {
                    bool hasLocalAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
                    if (hasLocalAccount || OAuthWebSecurity.GetAccountsFromUserName(User.Identity.Name).Count > 1)
                    {
                        OAuthWebSecurity.DeleteAccount(provider, providerUserId);
                        scope.Complete();
                        message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
                    }
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = message });
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Manage

        public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
        {
            ViewBag.StatusMessage =
                message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
                : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
                : "";
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Manage

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Manage(LocalPasswordModel model)
        {
            bool hasLocalAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasLocalAccount;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            if (hasLocalAccount)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather than return false in certain failure scenarios.
                    bool changePasswordSucceeded;
                    try
                    {
                        changePasswordSucceeded = WebSecurity.ChangePassword(User.Identity.Name, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        changePasswordSucceeded = false;
                    }

                    if (changePasswordSucceeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // User does not have a local password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing
                // OldPassword field
                ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
                if (state != null)
                {
                    state.Errors.Clear();
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        WebSecurity.CreateAccount(User.Identity.Name, model.NewPassword);
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Unable to create local account. An account with the name \"{0}\" may already exist.", User.Identity.Name));
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            return new ExternalLoginResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
            if (!result.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }

            if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // If the current user is logged in add the new account
                OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
                string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
                ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = result.UserName, ExternalLoginData = loginData });
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginConfirmation(RegisterExternalLoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            string provider = null;
            string providerUserId = null;

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !OAuthWebSecurity.TryDeserializeProviderUserId(model.ExternalLoginData, out provider, out providerUserId))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Insert a new user into the database
                using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
                {
                    UserProfile user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.ToLower() == model.UserName.ToLower());
                    // Check if user already exists
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        // Insert name into the profile table
                        db.UserProfiles.Add(new UserProfile { UserName = model.UserName });
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(provider, providerUserId, model.UserName);
                        OAuthWebSecurity.Login(provider, providerUserId, createPersistentCookie: false);

                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.");
                    }
                }
            }

            ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(provider).DisplayName;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginsList(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return PartialView("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", OAuthWebSecurity.RegisteredClientData);
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult RemoveExternalLogins()
        {
            ICollection<OAuthAccount> accounts = OAuthWebSecurity.GetAccountsFromUserName(User.Identity.Name);
            List<ExternalLogin> externalLogins = new List<ExternalLogin>();
            foreach (OAuthAccount account in accounts)
            {
                AuthenticationClientData clientData = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(account.Provider);

                externalLogins.Add(new ExternalLogin
                {
                    Provider = account.Provider,
                    ProviderDisplayName = clientData.DisplayName,
                    ProviderUserId = account.ProviderUserId,
                });
            }

            ViewBag.ShowRemoveButton = externalLogins.Count > 1 || OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
            return PartialView("_RemoveExternalLoginsPartial", externalLogins);
        }

        #region Helpers
        private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        public enum ManageMessageId
        {
            ChangePasswordSuccess,
            SetPasswordSuccess,
            RemoveLoginSuccess,
        }

        internal class ExternalLoginResult : ActionResult
        {
            public ExternalLoginResult(string provider, string returnUrl)
            {
                Provider = provider;
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            }

            public string Provider { get; private set; }
            public string ReturnUrl { get; private set; }

            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication(Provider, ReturnUrl);
            }
        }

        private static string ErrorCodeToString(MembershipCreateStatus createStatus)
        {
            // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=177550 for
            // a full list of status codes.
            switch (createStatus)
            {
                case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
                    return "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                    return "A user name for that e-mail address already exists. Please enter a different e-mail address.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
                    return "The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
                    return "The e-mail address provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
                    return "The password retrieval answer provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion:
                    return "The password retrieval question provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
                    return "The user name provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError:
                    return "The authentication provider returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected:
                    return "The user creation request has been canceled. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

                default:
                    return "An unknown error occurred. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Models\AccountModels.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models
{
    public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterExternalLoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string ExternalLoginData { get; set; }
    }

    public class LocalPasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Current password")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
        [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExternalLogin
    {
        public string Provider { get; set; }
        public string ProviderDisplayName { get; set; }
        public string ProviderUserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: All you have done with your `Ticket ticket = new Ticket{ ... }` line of code is set the value of 2 properties - `Issue` and `IssuedTo` - No where have you set a value for `CategoryID`. And study the DotNetFiddle again - you still have multiple other errors.

Comment: Why do you have `public int Author { get; set; }` in the Ticket model? Should `CategoryID = model.CategoryID` be enough?https://dotnetfiddle.net/DOiFs2

Comment: The DotNetFiddle included a property `Author` to describe the user who created the Ticket (which I assume your referring to as UserID`). Since your `Ticket` needs 2 properties for users (the user who created it, and the user (administrator) its been assigned to), then you should name your properties to describe what they actually are - which is what I did in the fiddle - I named them `Author` and `IssuedTo` (but they could be `CreatedBy` and `Administrator` or what ever you want - just make them meaningful)

Comment: I added `CategoryID = model.CategoryID` and `Author = model.UserID,` but since Author is type int? and UserID is type int should i just cast it?

Comment: You can always make it `int` rather than `int?`. But you don't seem to be understanding the logic here. Your creating a new ticket and that ticket should be assigned to the current user. The current user should not be able to create a ticket for another user. You should not evenhave a dropdownlist for that property. You only assign the value of `Author (or `UserID`) in the POST method just before you save the data model.

Comment: But try and make some effort to understand the code in your POST method. Your first `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` is correct except that you need to change the `ConfigureViewModel()` method to also create the `SelectList`'s for AllUsers and Categories (why on earth you need AllUsers only you know). Then you create the `Ticket` data model and you need to set **all** its properties including `CategoryID`. But the 2nd `if (ModelState.IsValid)` block is pointless - it is already valid (if it wasn't) you would never have got this far.

Comment: Then once you call `db.SaveChanges()` you need to redirect. There is no point calling `return View();` and if you do then it will just start throwing errors because you have not populated the `SelectList`'s. And finally you need to delete the last 4 line of your code - it can never even reach them because you have already exited the method

Comment: I'm just confused about the UserID part. If I take out the dropdown list for User ID then how would the application know who created the ticket? Anyone can go on the site and create a ticket with nothing to differentiate between them?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Surely your uses login, so therefore you know who the current user is. So in the POST method, then the set `UserID = theCurrentUserId`

Comment: I've added a "AccountController" and "AccountModels" into the question. This codes were not written by me but all I know is that whenever I register an account it'll save it somewhere. Where do I get theCurrentUserID?

Comment: [mvc websecurity get userid](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mvc+WebSecurity+get+userid)